# Labels position in Qgis

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm using QGIS 2.10.1.
Is there a way to avoid labels of different layers overlapping each other?

Comment: It does that by default for me. What exactly do you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a feature at this time which would do this automatically. You would have to **manually** set the *offsets* and *placements* for each layer's labels.

You could always open a [ticket](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) (feature request) to the QGIS developers and hope they implement this in a future QGIS version.